# Error Inserting event on Google Calendar (GSUITE): Read timed out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

We have an error trying to insert an event on a Google Calendar affecting diferents GSUITE basic accounts.
We are using a ServiceAccount to create the credential for the connection, and this is working fine, we can read, insert or delete events on each Calendar account.
The problem started from two days ago when the code reach this point, it doesnt receive a response.

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).setSendNotifications(sendNotificationMail).execute()
```

We have tried to increment the connection and request timeout like this example (unsuccessfully):

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/errors

After increment request timeout more than 60sec, we had this response:

```
503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "The service is currently unavailable.",
  "status" : "UNAVAILABLE"
}
```

We have more than 20 accounts inserting events successfully, and start appearing only in few accounts, but we are afraid that it will expand.
The accounts doesn't have reach any limit of usage(an affected account only inserted 5 events).

If you can help me I would be very grateful.
Thank you

Comment: Wonder if its related to this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141704931

Answer (score 0):

### As mentioned above, using a service account for the Calendar API recently leads to errors, especially when [sending notifications](https://issuetracker.google.com/140746812) and [creating events with invitees](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761425) in general

Whilst the corresponding requests usually results in 403 errors and 503 errors are more often due to [user errors](https://issuetracker.google.com/36758328) or [temporarily issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507320/google-calendar-api-v3-returns-503-backenderror-on-channel-creation), I recommend you to adjust to the current workaround and use service accounts for the Calendar API only in conjunction with [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

That is, enable in the Admin console domain-wide delegation, provide the necessary scope and implement in your code that the serviec account shall act on behalf of a domain user (e.g. the admin). This is the recommended procedure described in the [documentaiton for Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#perform-g-suite-domain-wide-delegation-of-authority).